# Change button text with values get from database

Tags: c#, database, button

I want to change button text with values get from database unfortunately all buttons take the same text

```
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\ARANL\\Menu.accdb");
con.Open();
//OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT Nummer,Speisename FROM Pizza", con); bunun bir anlamı yok.
//DataSet ds = new DataSet(); buna da gerek yok bildiğim kadarıyla.
OleDbCommand kmt = new OleDbCommand("SELECT Nummer,Speisename FROM Pizza", con);// o kodu buraya geçtik.
OleDbDataReader oku = kmt.ExecuteReader();
//da.Fill(ds); buna da
//DataTable dt = new DataTable();

var data = new Dictionary <string, object>();
while (oku.Read())
{
  data.Add(oku["Nummer"].ToString(), oku["Speisename"].ToString());
}
con.Close();
button50.Text = data["button50"].ToString();
button51.Text = data["button51"].ToString();
button52.Text = data["button52"].ToString();
button53.Text = data["button53"].ToString();
button54.Text = data["button54"].ToString();
```

Comment: You're assigning the value of the same variable to button50,51 and 52 text without changing it in between, so they will get the same text.

Comment: Thanks for your reply I don't know how to do that, please correct my code

Comment: I have inserted my database photo to see what I want to do

Comment: How many rows are coming back from your SQL call?  As this looks like homework here's a hint - you will want to loop through your dataset returned and write into an array or collection or? (you as the programmer determine),.  You then read through this array and assign the 1st to the 1st button, 2nd to the 2bd button etc.

Comment: Thank you for your advice two lines come back from my access database

Comment: I have changed the code, unfortunately it does not get errors

I added the above contribution

Comment: Two problems: If you get two rows back how are you setting the values for three buttons.  Also, you're still setting the each button to the first row returned.  Hint - you will need a foreach when reading your dataset.

Comment: Thanks for your help I did business here are my code